# What is @Autowired doing in this code

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Need to understand what is `@Autowired` doing in this code. I am kind of confused with the `scope=session`? Does it mean now the `user` is available in the `HttpSession`? How do I retrieve it from a `HttpSession`? If I remove `redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("user", user);` then I don't see the user in `JSP` page?

User class and its mapped as below

```
<bean id="user" class="example.User" scope="session">
  <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

Controller below redirects to another Controller which does not contain anything but a location to the landing page.jsp

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("user")
private User user;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    logger.info("post");
    new UserValidator().validate(user, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "login";
    }
    else {
        status.setComplete();           
        logger.info("Email Id: " + user.getEmailId());          
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("user", user);          
        return "redirect:/landing.htm";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Scope session means that user object will be kept for until the clients session is destroyed. It doesn't mean that you have it in HttpSession object. 
@Autowired annotation is used to wire user bean automatically. It's used to get bean from the application context and assign it to the local variable in your Java class.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear